# Use pkexec to run emacs in GUI mode with root privileges or any other way to do that

Tags: gui

I've recently started learning to use Emacs.

I do not want to run **emacs** using `sudo emacs` (lets not ask why), so I tried [using pkexec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo) to start emacs with root privileges. However, `pkexec emacs` starts **emacs** in terminal mode. How can I solve this?

Or is there any other alternative where I can possibly use **emacs** to edit files with `root` privileges.

This is the custom [policy](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
"-//freedesktop//DTD polkit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
"https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/policyconfig-1.dtd">

<policyconfig>
    <action id="com.ubuntu.pkexec.emacs">
    <description>Run Emacs with root privileges</description>
    <message>
        Authentication is required to run Emacs with root privileges
    </message>
    <icon_name>Emacs</icon_name>

    <defaults>
        <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
        <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
        <allow_active>>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>

    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/emacs</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
    </action>
</policyconfig>
```

Note:

- A similar policy for `brackets` works fine.
- Emacs starts in GUI mode if I use either `emacs` or `sudo emacs` in terminal.

Any help is appreciated.

Emacs version 24.5.1 in ubuntu 16.10

Comment: You do not need to run emacs as root to be able to edit system files. You could use `tramp` https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode . For example try opening the file at path: `//sudo:root@localhost:/etc/group`

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot. I didn't know that. Now, I look like an idiot having asked that question :)

Comment: No, you do not. Besides, with tramp you could also edit files on a remote computer using ssh (and other protocols), this is pretty nice. :) For editing with `sudo` also have a look here: http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/edit-files-as-root/

Comment: I think I'll reword my question a little bit so that you can incorporate your comments along with some more helpful guide as answer. I think that way it'll fit the stackexchange model and help other users like me. Thank you! once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative, to `pkexec emacs` or `sudo emacs`, would be to run emacs as normal user and work with `tramp-mode` to access files.

`tramp-mode` enables you to open files with root rights using access methods like `sudo`, `su`, `ssh`, `sftp` and so on, [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Inline-methods).

For example use this `C-x C-f` `//sudo:root@localhost:/etc/group` `RET` to open systems group file.

`tramp` also enables you to open files on remote hosts (tunneling and multihops are also possible).

For helper functions to reopen an already opened file as root, have a look [here](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/edit-files-as-root/).

Comment: I'd like to add that this is the preferred method. Emacs is run a very complex program to be givne permanent privilege escalation, so in the spirit of polkit, it only requests them when it needs the PE, and relinquishes as soon as the buffer is closed.